# Prove or disprove: $h:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, h(x)=\left | ln(x+1) \right |$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

> Prove or disprove: $h:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, h(x)=\left |
> ln(x+1) \right |$ is differentiable

I would test the differentiability at $x_{0}=-1$ but that wouldn't make sense here because our interval excludes negative values: $(0, \infty)$.

$$h'(x) = \left|\frac{1}{x+1}\right|$$

$\Rightarrow$

$h$ is differentiable

Just as additional question, it really wouldn't have been differentiable if $-1$ was included, right?

Did I do everything correctly?

Comment: I would like to highlight your curious mistake about derivative of $|\log(x + 1)|$ as  $|1/(x + 1)|$. Note that by chain rule $|f(x)|' = \operatorname{sign}(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$ because $|x|' = \operatorname{sign}(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is defined on $(0,\infty)$, so it doesn't make sense to check whether it is differentiable at $-1$.

Since $\ln(x+1)>0$ for $x+1>1$, that is, $x>0$, you can write your function as
$$
h(x)=\ln(x+1)
$$
and you see there's no problem in differentiability anywhere (in the domain).

---

**Note 1.** It's generally wrong to say that, if $h(x)=|f(x)|$, then $h'(x)=|f'(x)|$. Consider, for instance, $h(x)=|x|$; then $h'(x)=1$ if $x>0$ and $h'(x)=-1$ if $x<0$.

**Note 2.** The given function would show a problem in differentiability if the domain was set to $(-1,\infty)$. Try see why, looking at the behavior at $0$.

Comment: Thank you for answer! If this task would give me 2 points, how many points you would have given me for my solution?

I think for $-1$ it wouldn't be differentiable because we would get in non derivated and derivated function to an undefined expression.
For the non derivated function we would get $ln(0)$ and for the derivated $\frac{1}{0}$ and thus the function isn't differentiable.
And by the way, did I get correctly that modulus is completely useless here since the interval only includes positive values?

Comment: @cnmesr It makes no sense trying to see whether a function is differentiable where it is not even defined. The error about the modulus is bad, I'm afraid. It's true that, for $x>0$, $\left|\frac{1}{x+1}\right|=\frac{1}{x+1}$ (the right-hand side being the true derivative), but the presence of the modulus means you didn't catch how to proceed in this case and used the wrong $h'(x)=|f'(x)|$ I mentioned in my note 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers, strictly speaking, are correct, but I suspect that the reasonings that led you to them are not.

The function $h$ is positive. Also, the function defined by
$$g(x)=\ln(x+1)$$
for $x>0$ is positive and equal to $h$, so
$$h'(x)=g'(x)=\frac1{x+1}$$

**But**, in general, the derivative of $|f|$ is not $|f'|$.

About the second answer, if we try to extend naturally (i.e., with the same definition) the function to an interval that contains $-1$, it is still non-differentiable (and non-continuous) at $-1$, because the limit
$$\lim_{x\to-1^+}\ln(x+1)$$
is not finite.

**But** the interesting problem is checking diffirentiability at $0$. If the domain of $h$ "were" $(-1,\infty)$ then the absolute value bars would be not superfluous, that is, they'd do change the sign for some values of $x$. Since the absolute value function is not differentiable, perhaps $|\ln(\cdot+1)|$ neither is.